# Playwright element Location using properties

Tags: c#, playwright

The app that I'm testing contains a free text field on which I'd like to enter some text and assert the value.

Locating the field and entering the text is not a problem, when the field is in its initial state, I can validate that the field is visible and that contains an empty string:

```
textField = page.Locator("div[data-ph-key='Default textarea'] textarea")

await Expect(textField).ToBeVisibleAsync();
await Expect(textField).ToHaveTextAsync("");
```

When I want to enter some new text and check the text value from the field the test fails due to the actual value being an empty string.

```
await textField.TypeText("test string");
await Page.Keyboard.PressAsync("Enter");
await Expect(textField).ToContainTextAsync("test string");
```

On inspection I can see the DOM is not being updated directly with the new string value entered, rather its being updated in the properties tab as shown below:

[image]

Is there a way I can get that text value to use in my Expect statement?

Below is the code being used for the test

```
public async Task CheckTextEntry()
{await Page.ClickAsync("text='Textarea'");
//create page instance
TextAreaPage textAreaPage = new TextAreaPage(Page);
//check default text is visible and empty
Expect(textAreaPage.DefaultTextFieldValue).ToBeVisibleAsync();

await Expect(textAreaPage.DefaultTextFieldValue).ToHaveTextAsynnc 
("");
// enter some text
await textAreaPage.TypeText(textAreaPage.DefaultTextField, 
"my text value");
// press enter in  order to update the native text value in the 
//  element properties
await Page.Keyboard.PressAsync("Enter");
// attempt to verify the new text value
await Expect(textAreaPage.DefaultTextField).ToHaveJSPropertyAsync
("value", "my text value");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the value of the field in your case by doing the following which certainly works for me.  Didn't know this could be done until I looked into it a bit deeper :)

```
await Expect(textField).ToHaveJSPropertyAsync("value", "your value");
```

[Method help on Playwright.dev](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/test-assertions#locator-assertions-to-have-js-property)

I hope this helps.

Comment: The form is probably submitted by pressing the Enter key: 
`await Page.Keyboard.PressAsync("Enter");`

Comment: The page does not have a submit button as it is part of a cheat sheet area being used to develop and test various controls. The page is not hooked up to anything so pressing enter does not submit anything. Refreshing the page returns all field back to their initial (empty values)

Comment: @bobe_b I have updated my reply as I found the answer.  The equivalent for me in typescript certainly works.

Comment: Thanks @AJG  I tried await Expect(textField).ToHaveJSPropertyAsync("value", "my value");   This sort kind of works because it brings bac the expected value, however i get back an exception from playwright as follows:

Comment: However I get back an exception from playwright as follows:      Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException : Locator expected to have JavaScript property 'value' ' my value'
But was: ' my value '                                                                                                                     Am I missing something somewhere?

Comment: @bobe_b can you post your code please?

Comment: Thanks @AJG, ive updated my original post with the code being used

Comment: @bobe_b You are setting the field to be empty first by using textAreaPage.DefaultTextFieldValue but are then setting and verifying the typed value using textAreaPage.DefaultTextField not .DefaultTextFieldValue, is that right?  Looks like you should do await Expect(textAreaPage.DefaultTextFieldValue).ToHaveJSPropertyAsync
("value", "my text value");

Comment: Thanks @AJG that was a typo on my part which ive  corrected. In answer to your question, I was not setting the field to be empty using  textAreaPage.DefaultTextFieldValue. DefaultTextFieldValue is a locator within the textAreaPage. Its default state is empty so im just verifying that it is infact empty before setting a value.

Comment: @AJG i managed to get it working now. After correcting the typo for the element locator to Expect(textAreaPage.DefaultTextFieldValue).ToHaveJSPropertyAsync ("value", "my text value"); The test was still failing. Im not quite sure what affect the key press function was having on the behaviour but removing it from the code seems to work!  This is the line in question which when removed creates a passing test: 
    await Page.Keyboard.PressAsync("Enter");